# Custom segue animations using SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using SWRevealViewController for the main menu on my app.

For one menu item I have several UIViewControllers each with their own UINavigationController. in each view I have bottom Tool bar buttons that show(push) to each view.

Currently the segue animations always swipe left. I would like to disable the animation and tried to set up some custom animations but because I'm using SWRevealViewController I have no idea how to do that.

Each way I've tried loses the revealViewController and access to the menu.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I've played around with the different segue types and found something that works for no animation.

Set the Segue type to present Modally in IB. set Presentation to current context (default will stop SWReveal working) and uncheck Animates

Creating custom animations or transitions is beyond my expertise at the moment, but this works for what I want to achieve.